# is $\sin x/(k+\cos x)$ strictly monotonically increasing

Tags: analysis

i want to find out if 
$\sin x/(k+\cos x)$
is strictly monotonically increasing for $0<x< \pi$ and a constant $k>0$.
Plotting the function suggests this is true.

Comment: is $k$ assumed to be positive?

Answer (score 3):

If $k < 1$ then there will be some value of $x$ such that $k + \cos x = 0$ and the function is undefined.

If $k > 1$ then as $x$ approaches $\pi$ then the numerator starts to approach 0 (while the denominator is greater than 0).  And since f(x) is clearly positive elsewhere this would go against the proposition of a monotonic function.

If $k = 1$ the $f(x)$ is not defined at $\pi$ but the domain is the open interval $(0,\pi)$ so this is not a problem.  And the the numerator and denominator are both going to $0.$

And in fact $\lim_\limits{x\to \pi^-} f(x) = \infty$

In this case the function is monotonic over the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.